# Regex to detect if a character appears only once in the same string

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, slack

I'm creating a slack slash command and I want to send the body text along the lines of `/command send @jay some flowers` but I want to send an error is the command contains either no @handles or more than one.

The way I've written the code at the minute uses regex to validate that a handle exists `/.*\@.*/` but I am going mad trying to handle the edge cases and get some validation around detecting one and only 1 @ symbol.

I'm validating it in javascript inside a Gscript web service if that's any help

Any thoughts?
thx

Comment: you could simply check `if (yourString.match(/\@/g).length !== 1) { // OK } else { // NOT OK }`

Comment: Yeah, There's a couple of ways to do it in code quite easily, but I built the prototype to look for a full regex match and then I got stuck down the rabbit hole of trying to update it without adding to the code. I am almost certainly into sunk cost territory but I've just got know at this stage... thanks for your answer though

Comment: If possible, please kindly upvote the answers that turned out helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two expressions for negative and positive checks:

- Matching a string that has no @handles or has at least two: `/^(?!.*@\w)|@\w.*@\w/` - see [proof](https://regex101.com/r/DIpk3n/1)
- Matching a string that only has one @handle: `/^(?!.*@\w.*@\w).*@\w/` - see [proof](https://regex101.com/r/DIpk3n/2).

I think your @handle must be `@`  + a word character, not a single `@`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that without using a regex by just split the string using `@` and check that the array resulting only contains 2 strings:

```js
const isUnique = (char, string) => {
  return string.split(char).length === 2
}

console.log(isUnique('@', '/command send @jay some flowers'))
console.log(isUnique('@', '/command @send @jay some flowers'))
```

Comment: That would return true event if the string does not contain any '@'; the return statement should be `return string.split(char).length === 2;`

Comment: @secan ooup thanks for the reminder I updated my answer :)